# Difficulty understanding logic of the implemented algorithm - C#

Tags: c#, integer

I am finding it hard to understand the logic of the following algorithm that outputs 8,8. I would appreciate if you could provide some insight.

```
using System;

namespace Console_Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(g(4) + g(5) + "," + g(6));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int g(int k)
        {
            if ((k == 1) || (k == 2))

                return 1;
            else

                return g(k - 1) + g(k - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jusz debug the function and you´ll find out yourself. Anyway your question has a **horrible** title. It should contain the **relevant** information.

Comment: What do you expect the code to do?

Comment: i know what the output is i want to know how did it come this way i calculated by my self and i got 5,6

Comment: Write down what how you expected it to behave, debug it, and compare its behaviour with what you think should do. Also, start with easier calls to the function (pass it small numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: 8,8 is correct (debugged on paper)

Comment: That looks like a Fibonnaci sequence implementation

Answer (score 1):

Just a recursive function. You have to follow all steps.

if k = 1:
return 1;

if k = 2:
return 1;

if k = 3:
return (g(2) + g(1))    result is: 1 + 1 = 2

if k = 4:
return (g(3) + g(2))    result is: (1 + 1) + 1 = 3

if k = 5:
return (g(4) + g(3))    result is: 5 + 3 = 5

if k = 6:
return (g(5) + g(4))    result is: 5 + 3 = 8

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to the [Fibonacci sequence (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), where each number is the sum of the two previous numbers.

Because it is a recursive function, look at the `return g(k - 1) + g(k - 2);` where it calls itself, you must follow all the recursion until it ends.

- g(1): **1** -- Because the return 1;
- g(2): **1** -- Because the return 1;
- g(3): g(2) + g(1) = 1 + 1 = **2** -- Here starts the recursion
- g(4): g(3) + g(2) = 2 + 1 = **3**
- g(5): g(4) + g(3) = 3 + 2 = **5**
- g(6): g(5) + g(4) = 5 + 3 = **8**

So `g(4) + g(5) +"," +g(6)` would be:

> 3 + 5 , 8 = 8, 8

Pretty much the sum of the F4 F5 resulting in the F6 value.

[image]

A better implementation of the Fibonacci sequence would be

```cs
static int Fibonacci(int k)
{
    if(k < 0) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Fibonnaci works with numbers >= 0");

    if (k == 0 || k == 1)
        return k;
    else                
        return Fibonacci(k - 1) + Fibonacci(k - 2);
}
```